# Can I use headphone extension cord as USB 2.0 data to webcam?

Tags: usb, cables, usb-device

I have read that "slow", presumable USB 2.0, can only run 3 meters, while fast USB can run 5 meters. I have a long headphone jack extension, and I'd like to use it to access a webcam in another room. I see adapters for this, but I'd like to ask here. Can I run a video-only webcam using an AUX to USB 2.0 adapter? Thank you.

[EDIT]
Also I'd like to ask for the case of a webcam with audio and video, on USB 2.0. Thank you.

Comment: USB uses four wires, V+, D+, D- and GND. A headphone jack is 3-pole. What is your plan?

Comment: What kind of connection do you have at the webcam?

Comment: USB needs a cable that is designed for USB. Use anything else and that will simply not work (except specific circumstances and at very short distances). A headphone cable isn't designed for USB so it will not work for USB.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no you can't use random headphone wiring you don't know anything about for USB 2.0 signaling. It requires a twisted pair with specific impedance for differential signaling and thick enough wires for supplying the rated amount of current without too much losses. Get a USB extension cable.